# how to execute client script before LoginStatus onloggedout event

Tags: asp.net, client-side-scripting

Good Day to All,
I need to excecute a client script before OnLoggedOut event of Login status control of asp.net

I've tried to put

```
LoginStatus1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:limparDadosSalvamentoAutomatico();");
```

but it does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the Href attribute

```
LoginStatus1.Attributes["href"] = string.Format("javascript: limparDadosSalvamentoAutomatico(); __doPostBack('{0}','')", loginStatus.Controls[0].UniqueID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "yourfunction();", True)
```